# Analysing local features on rasters using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, topography

I have several raster datasets representing the elevation on a beach (See Picture).
The beach topography include beach cusps (which represent local max on the beach).
I want to extract some statistical information from these features, including their height, their width, and their length in relation to their location on the beach.

I'm looking to find a way to extract this information using ArcGIS Pro but haven't been able to do so.

Does anyone has suggestions on how to do this in ArcGIS Pro?

[image]